# Update Multiple columns of multiple rows using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Entity framework for building an app.

Table to be updated.

```
[Id] [CheckItemId]  [Checked]  [Comment]
1      100             1          abc
2      150             0          xyz
```

Class:

```
public class CheckListRequest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public static void UpdateCheckList(List<CheckListRequest> checkList){

}
```

How do I update the table multiple column like (Checked,comment) with the values coming in list from frontend using LINQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `dbContext` is your `DataContext` and `Id` is the primary key of the table, try this:

```
public static void UpdateCheckList(List<CheckListRequest> checkList)
{
    foreach (CheckListRequest clr in checkList)
    {
        CheckListRequest clrInDB = dbContext.CheckListRequests.SingleOrDefault(o.Id == clr.Id);
        clrInDB.IsChecked = clr.IsChecked;
        clrInDB.Comment = clr.Comment;
    }

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: do the savechanges neeed to come inside the loop to make the changes every time the loop runs...

Comment: That depends on your requirements, let's say you update 10 records and the 4th record fails, do you want to rollback the change of the first three records?

Comment: You can reduce that .Where(..).SingleOrDefault() to a single SingleOrDefault(...) call by the way ;-)

Comment: no rollback is needed even if some record fails it will be logged by other methods.

Comment: @ankur in that case you can put `dbContext.SaveChanges()` inside the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

> How do I update the table multiple column like (Checked,comment) with the values

Exactly the same way you'd update only one column...

1. Get the entity from context
2. Update column/columns
3. Call `SaveChanges()` method on context.

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var entity = ctx.Table.First(t => t.Id == myId);
    entity.Prop1 = "newValue";
    entity.Prop2 = 23;

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: there are multiple ids coming , what i meant is there are at least 10 object in the List<CheckListRequest> checkList) ,each object corresponds to a row in database so how do i update multiple columns  of the table rows by taking values from the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach loop on your list as below:

```
public static void UpdateCheckList(List<CheckListRequest> checkList)
{
    checkList.foreach(CL =>{
              CheckListRequest objCLR= DataContext.CheckListRequests
              .SingleOrDefault(E => E.Id == CL.Id);
        objCLR.IsChecked = CL.IsChecked;
        objCLR.Comment = CL.Comment;
        });

    DataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ForEachAsync or ForEach like below

```
var actionTakenOnEndorsement = _context.Endorsement.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.IsApproved != null).OrderBy(o => o.SolutionId).ThenByDescending(o => o.ModifiedOn).DistinctBy(x => new { x.SolutionId, x.UserId }).AsQueryable();
                
await actionTakenOnEndorsement.ForEachAsync(x => { x.IsEndorsementRevoked = true; x.Comment = "Revoked by system"; });
```